# Artifacts similar to overlapping polygon faces

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I have a number of cubes in the scene. All of these cubes, have 6 sides, always. Some cubes, are next to each other. The problem shows itself as viewed in the figure below. Strange artifacts occur, where it seems there are overlapping triangles. I have tried changing the backculling, to no avail. This does not see to be the major issue though, as seen in the figure the bottom cube does not have a top cube on it, but still displays the artifacts on top.

[image]

If I scale the position of the vertices, the problem largely disappears.

```
State.glClearDepthf(1);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glDisable(GL_BLEND);
State.glDepthMask(true);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glCullFace(GL_BACK);
blockShader.begin();
terrain.getTexture().bind(0);
blockShader.setUniformMatrix("worldTrans", transform);
blockShader.setUniformf("cameraPos", camera.position);
blockShader.setUniformMatrix("projTrans", camera.combined);
terrain.render(blockShader);
blockShader.end();
```

I am using the following vertices for my cubes. I add the x,y,z position (which is an integer) to each of the vertex floats appropriately. I have checked myself that these vertices are all CW aligned.

```
static float[] CUBE = {
        0f,0f,0f, // triangle 1 : begin
        0f,0f, 1f,
        0f, 1f, 1f, // triangle 1 : end

        1f, 1f,0f, // triangle 2 : begin
        0f,0f,0f,
        0f, 1f,0f, // triangle 2 : end

        1f,0f, 1f,
        0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,

        1f, 1f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,
        0f,0f,0f,

        0f,0f,0f,
        0f, 1f, 1f,
        0f, 1f,0f,

        1f,0f, 1f,
        0f,0f, 1f,
        0f,0f,0f,

        0f, 1f, 1f,
        0f, 0f, 1f,
        1f,0f, 1f,

        1f, 1f, 1f,
        1f,0f,0f,
        1f, 1f,0f,

        1f,0f,0f,
        1f, 1f, 1f,
        1f,0f, 1f,

        1f, 1f, 1f,
        1f, 1f,0f,
        0f, 1f,0f,

        1f, 1f, 1f,
        0f, 1f,0f,
        0f, 1f, 1f,

        1f, 1f, 1f,
        0f, 1f, 1f,
        1f,0f, 1f
};
```

I am using LibGDX. Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit:

#### The following I use to create the multiple cubes:

```
    float[] spawn = new float[CUBE.length];

    System.arraycopy( CUBE, 0, spawn, 0, CUBE.length );

    for (int i = 0; i < spawn.length; i+=3) {
        spawn[i] += x * 1.01f;
        spawn[i+1] += y * 1.01f;
        spawn[i+2] += z * 1.01f;
    }

    vertices.put(spawn);
```

Note the **1.01f.** If I add it the problem disappears mostly.
[image]

If I remove the **1.01f**, the first image applies where the problem clearly shows. This seems to be duplicated vertices, but I cannot find them. Also noteworthy; if I change the CUBE array **1.f's** to **0.9f's** I would assume the problem would largely disappear to, but that is not the case.

### Edit:

My near is 1f and far is 100f. So there does the problem not lie either.

### Edit:

I made a crucial error, which was bound to be. It happened in the shader.

```
vec3 color = mod(v_vertex, 1.0) * 16.0;
```

was used to calculate the color, since I didn't have normals,uv's or colors. However, a lot of my vertices are positioned at 1.0 (or a multiple). Sometimes apparently the mod would result in slightly less than 1, other times it would be 0.

This was one of my fixes:

```
vec3 color = mod(v_vertex + 0.01, 1.0) * 16.0;
```

Now the top will be 1.01 and mod back to 0.01, which is already better. However I would like the color to be 0.0 - 1.0 and not wrap around. If someone can answer that, I have my final answer.

Comment: Why are you rendering several cubes inside each other?

Comment: They shouldn't be inside each other, I hope that's not the case. However, I always need to render the 6 six sides for each cube, also when they are next to each other (later on there will be transparency and so on).

Comment: To properly solve this, it would help if you included your projection matrix and the bit-depth of your depth buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
vec4 mod = mod(v_vertex,1.0);
gl_FragColor = mod + 0.999*(1-step(0.001, mod));
```

This takes anything that rounded to slightly more than one (such that mod reduces it to almost zero) and adds enough to get it back up near one.

Comment: While this code might answer the question you should add some explanation on why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the cubes ranged from 0.0001f to 0.999f instead of 0f and 1f, which solves all issues.